# Ionic Project works with heroku local but not on web

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, heroku, deployment, web-deployment

I've created a very simple project with ionic angular and tried to deploy it on heroku. While the project works perfectly fine when I run heroku local, I get an error when I open it on the web.

The project is supposed to run on a NodeJs Server.

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "forgot-password2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~12.1.1",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~12.0.1",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.16.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.16.1",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

This is my Procfile:

```
web: npm run build && npm start
```

Why is it not working? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: use httpserver on your www folder made by npm build.

Comment: what does that mean? what exactly should I do?